# Kubernetes Deployment with GPU

Tags: docker, tensorflow, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy a ML app on Kubernetes engine with GPU. I created the docker image using nvidia/cuda:9.0-runtime and built my app above it. When I deploy the image to Kubernetes Engine I get an error saying that it could not import libcuda.so.1.

```
ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I looked at few solutions posted but none of them seem to work.

When trying those solutions I also found that

the paths mentioned by

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

which gives

```
/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
```

do not seem to exist.

As well as there isn't a file with the name libcuda.so.1 (or any number) anywhere within the file system. And the /usr/lib/cuda/lib64 contains the shared libraries. 
Am I currently implementing anything wrong here

Comment: Could you please share your application Dockerfile and application pod/daemonset/deployment YAML?

Answer (score 1):

You are facing that issue as you have not installed the CUDA drivers on the cluster. Please follow the installing drivers section in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus). For verifying the installation you can run this command and check.

```
kubectl logs -n kube-system ds/nvidia-driver-installer -c nvidia-driver-installer
```

Answer (score -1):

The missing `libcuda.so` library issue on Kubernetes is most commonly associated with using the incorrect container image to run GPU workloads. Considering that you are already using the CUDA docker image, **try changing your CUDA version to one that is compatible with your workload**. I have encountered issues with a workload requiring 10.0 throwing the library not found with the CUDA9.0 base image.

Most cloud providers use containerd/Docker to run their CPU workloads, and **nvidia-docker** to provide the GPU support. The **nvidia-docker** is a thin layer that runs on top of the NVIDIA drivers, and is CUDA-agnostic. All of the CUDA library files and resources are solely contained in your container.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Will do. I used cuda 9.0 since they had mentioned in the document referred by Crou mentioned the Latest supported version was CUDA 9.0